# Why does using conditional logic in gravity forms break the form when placed using php

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

I have a form built using [gravity forms](https://www.gravityforms.com/)...

I am placing this form onto my page using PHP like this...

```
// set our form ID 'Order Checkout'
$form_id = 1;

// enqueue the necessary styles and scripts into head
gravity_form_enqueue_scripts($form_id,true);

...

// place my form onto page
gravity_form($form_id,false,true,false,null,true);
```

This works nicely and submits nicely...

[image]

But then when I apply conditional logic to a field, which validates and saves ok. The output on the page is this...

[image]

Form appears missing.

But in the inspector you can see all the scripts/styles and the form html have loaded ok, but for some reason on `#gform_wrapper_1` it has `style="display:none;"` applied to it.

[image]

If remove the inline style, all the conditional logic fields are visible and the conditional logic doesn't work.

Absolutely no console errors.

Any ideas why I might be seeing this. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any custom CSS or JS applied to this ID / Class from another external file ?

Comment: I figured it out i'm guna answer question in a sec. I had jquery loading again in the footer in my compiled main.js file. If I remove this jquery from loading a second time, it works.